# SignalR library throws error when it application run without debug points and work fine while debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I have created a .net core chat application using SignalR and I need move to next user by clicking next button. When I click the next button it will trigger the method "getRemoteClientNext" inside the Hub class

```
public async Task getRemoteClientNext(string RemoteUserId)
{

      var name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        var CurrentAppUser = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(name);

        if(RemoteUserId != null) {
            using (var db = _dBContext)
            {
                var remotename = db.Users.Find(RemoteUserId);

                var RemoteUser = db.Connections.Where(c => c.UsersId != CurrentAppUser.Result.Id && c.UsersId != RemoteUserId && c.RemoteConnected == false).AsEnumerable().GroupBy(c => c.UsersId);

                //var remoteConnection = db.Connections.Where(u => u.UsersId == CurrentAppUser.Result.Id || u.UsersId == RemoteUserId).ToList();
                //remoteConnection.ForEach(i => i.RemoteConnected = false);
                var currntUserConnection = db.Connections.Where(u => u.UsersId == CurrentAppUser.Result.Id).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
                currntUserConnection.RemoteConnected = false;
                db.SaveChanges();

                var RemoteUserConnection = db.Connections.Where(u => u.UsersId == RemoteUserId).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
                if (RemoteUserConnection != null)
                {
                    RemoteUserConnection.RemoteConnected = false;
                }
                db.SaveChanges();

                var connec = db.Connections.Where(c => c.UsersId == RemoteUserId);

                if (connec.Count() == 0)
                {
                    await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ClienErrors", "The user is no longer connected");
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var connection in connec)
                    {
                        await Clients.Client(connection.ConnectionID).SendAsync("maintainConnectionStatus", "Connecting a remote user......");
                    }

                }
                await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("maintainConnectionStatus", "Connecting a remote user......");

                if (RemoteUser.Count() == 0)
                {
                    await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("maintainConnectionStatus", "Connecting a remote user......");
                }
                else
                {
                    var selectedRemoteUser = RemoteUser.First().ToList();
                    var currentUserConnection = db.Connections.Where(u => u.UsersId == CurrentAppUser.Result.Id).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
                   // selectedRemoteUser.ForEach(c => c.RemoteConnected = true, c.Remo) ;
                    foreach(Connections con in selectedRemoteUser)
                    {
                        con.RemoteConnected = true;
                        con.RemoteConnectionID = currentUserConnection.ConnectionID;
                        currentUserConnection.RemoteConnectionID = con.ConnectionID;
                    }
                    // var currentUserConnection = db.Connections.Where(u => u.UsersId == CurrentAppUser.Result.Id).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
                    var RemoteId = selectedRemoteUser.Select(u => u.UsersId).FirstOrDefault();
                    var RemoteName = db.Users.Find(RemoteId);
                    currentUserConnection.RemoteConnected = true;

                    db.SaveChanges();

                    //var RemoteId = selectedRemoteUser.Select(u => u.UsersId).FirstOrDefault();
                    //var RemoteName = db.Users.Find(RemoteId);

                    var connec2 = db.Connections.Where(c => c.UsersId == RemoteId);

                    if (connec2.Count() ==0)
                    {
                        await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ClienErrors", "The user is no longer connected");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (var connection in connec2)
                        {
                            await Clients.Client(connection.ConnectionID).SendAsync("SendRemoteUserId", CurrentAppUser.Result.Id, CurrentAppUser.Result.FirstName);
                        }

                    }
                    await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("SendRemoteUserId", RemoteId, RemoteName.FirstName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

in java script the event is like

```
document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
connection.invoke("getRemoteClientNext", RemoteUserId);
});
```

The issue I got is when I click the next button "getRemoteClientNext" will be triggered and work fine when it is debugging. If I disable all the debug points and run the application this will not work. But other functions like sending the chat messages using hub are working finely. Then I check the console and I saw the error message

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: An unexpected error occurred invoking 'getRemoteClientNext' on the server.
at _this.callbacks. (signalr.js:2088)
at HubConnection.processIncomingData (signalr.js:2182)
at WebSocketTransport.HubConnection.connection.onreceive (signalr.js:1905)
at WebSocket.webSocket.onmessage (signalr.js:3949)
```

I removed the SignalR and try to install it again but it is not working and in add client side library also only showing Jquery.SignalR.js and Jquery.SignalR.min.js files. So I added Signalr.js file manually from another project.

Can any one tell me why this is happening is it error in SignalR library

Comment: Part of me thinks that you're facing a race condition, if when it has break points it works fine then that is probably a sign that by slowing it down and checking the breakpoints you enable it to succeed. Try wrapping the method in a try catch block, and see what the error is. Just put a break point in the catch, this way the try portion can run normally without any interruptions a debug would cause

Comment: Also this code has horrible structure, try seperating some logic (like the db stuff) and moving some stuff to functions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This smells like a race condition just as SomeStudent suggested. Reading through the first couple of lines of code inside the `getRemoteClient()` method, you are missing an `await`.

I can't say with 100% certainty this will fix it, but I'm certain it could become a problem even if this wasn't the culprit.

```cs
// Add await here.
var CurrentAppUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(name);
```

Comment: thank for you reply. when I use await program works correctly. Before I get this answer I used to sleep the thread for 2 seconds then also this works. so thanks again for showing the missing await